# fiscal year end average returns

Tags: sas

I have data in the format below with fiscal year start month and fiscal year end month.Using the daily observation for each calendar year, I want to find the average returns for each year such that it will end in the month of fiscal year end and not the end of month for calendar year which is Dec as firms have different fiscal year end.

Thus the average ret for firm A in 1991  will start from the seventh month of 1990 and end on the 6month of 1991 or using firm B the average ret in 1991 will start from the 11 month of 1990 and end on the 10month of 1991.

How do I solve this problem?.Thanks in advance for the assistance.

```
Compname       Date                    Ret           Fiscal year end month
A             1/01/1990                1.5              6
A             2/01/1990                1.6              6
A             3/01/1990                1.7              6
A             4/01/1990                1.8              6
.
.
.
.
A            31/12/2016              1.8                6
B            1/01/1990                2.5                10
B            2/01/1990                2.6                10
B            3/01/1990                2.7                10
B            4/01/1990                2.8                10
.
.
B            31/12/2016               2.5                10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding months and extracting the year.  Here is a method using `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    select compname, year(intnx('month', date, 12 - fy_end_month)) as fyyyy, avg(ret)
    from t
    group by compname, year(intnx('month', date, 12 - fy_end_month));
```

Comment: 407  proc sql;
408   select compname, year(intnx('month', date, 12 - fy_end_month) as fyyyy, avg(ret)
                                                           
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).
409   from ra.amid
410   group by compname, year(intnx('month', date, 12 - fy_end_month);
                                                        
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).

Comment: Double check that you have two close parentheses after fy_end_month on both the select clause and the group by, i.e. `12 - fy_end_month))`

Comment: Thanks for the directions. It's now running but taking long to complete....it's been running for almost an hour. Thanks

Comment: @Emma did you include the `QUIT;` There isn't one in the sample and it would leave SAS hanging if you didn't have it included.

Comment: @Reeza thanks very much and I apologise for the late update. please I added  quit however after the codes finished running the result window displayed nothing.please what can i do?

Comment: @Emma Without further information we can't help you. What does the log say?

Comment: @Reeza please when i run this message pops up NOTE: The query requires remerging summary statistics back with the original data...then it runs but nothing shows at the end.....please is it because there is no out= condition  in the codes.thanks

Comment: @Emma . . . The query should not be remerging if the aggregation keys are the same.  You might try `group by compname, fyyyy`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks. Its runs now but the results window displays this message: THIS PAGE CAN'T BE DISPLAYED. Hence cant see any output from the codes. Thanks once again.

Comment: If you put the field calculation in the `group by` section then it prints the same number of records as the input data. Therefore you need the field name (which can be preceded by the keyword `calculated` to show it's not in the original data.

Comment: A variation on the calculated field is `intnx(cats('year1.',fy_end_mth),date,0) as fy_start_mth format=date9.`

This will shift the starting month by the value of fiscal year end month +1. (e.g. year1.10 runs from October - September)